# Styling buttons with images?

Tags: html, css, forms

Ive been trying to style a submit button using an image. I would use CSS but the button is too complex design wise. I have tried adding a background image to a button but the image was badly positioned. I have also tried using

`<input type="image" src="myimage.png">`

But alas this is not a submit button so It doesn't work. I have looked and tried everything I believe possible but can't find a solution to making the button submit the form. Thanks.

Comment: `<input type="image">` is effectively a submit button, afaik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have different possibilities for a submit button:

```
<input type="image">
<input type="submit">
<button></button> <!-- no type needed, since submit is the default type -->
```

These are all submit buttons. Pick the one, which suits you best.

Now you can choose to put an image between the button or use background-images and position them properly.

Example for button with background-image:

```css
button {
  background:url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEgASAPYAAAAA/2NFB4tsE7KKCtCiDbWMCpFwDotwGdCgAe65FvjFKvjGLffDJNuqC5V1EaqJGPjHMPbKPvfOTLuRCo5yG+q3F/bEKG1SFdGjBvrcbeGuD2NFCY5wFfG+JPfNRpp1CLSOEfnJNPbOS/rPRsCSBmdJC8+mGvnLOv3ni/3nj/zkgPrUU9uqDWNCA9GoHfjSVfvie/rXW96tEmVHCreQFPnLP/fTXfrbdPzihf3qlP3mhsSYD5VzEPXEOffSWvrbcfzigP3rkqJ8DXFWFd2tFPrQSfnYYvvfdQAAAO7CNGVHDJh3DfLCK/nSUPraZ/zjfv3qkvzlhfvecqiCD2pNEL6TC/fGLvrSTfrbav3pjv3ojPzlgv3TT82kIWpOEZ55C+OyFfnMPvzdb/zda/3XWe/FOqiDEGpKAWZJDXNWEZt2B8KXDt6vHd+yIcifHKN+EXRTAmtQFmlMD2JCBWdIBmdIAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH/C05FVFNDQVBFMi4wAwEAAAAh+QQF+gAAACwAAAAAEgASAAYH/4AAgoN1dHNzcnGDi4Rwb25tbGtqaWiMgmdmZWRjYmNkYWBfXoxnXVxiW1pZWltYV1ZVVIRTXFJRWVC6WU9OTUxLSoJwSWO4SEi6yEdGRURDAHRCV0+5yFBByEA/Pj08SnQ7ZDrWSDlQyDg3NjU0M3MyMTrK5lnIMFgvNS4tLSwrKqCcS4FiC5AnUoxcOWGiRQkSI6ToQKFjy5OLR7DEEBECxBwvH6zEQALjIgwYGUd66MBhA4A0Gkb4QJIhgxQsTkaKOIHhgiAlXyyIaIKsKBIPNSpQmDPIy4QOYUSIkCDCQwQIFR7MYCTHQQMGC6woYJAAwYGtl2ZcMFCAAIEBAg0utLi0aMOGfgHmMgoEACH5BAkFAAAALAYABQAGAAMABgcMgFCCg1BBhodBgoaBACH5BAkKAAAALAYABQAGAAMABgcOgEhIUFCCgkFBhoOFSIEAIfkEAQUAAAAsBgAFAAYAAwAGBwyAUIKDUEGGh0GChoEAOw==) no-repeat 5px center;
  padding:5px 5px 5px 27px;
}
```

```html
<button type='submit'>Submit</button>
```

(Or as a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wRtpR))

Comment: hmmm.. I'll play around and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: Hey thanks you were right. Tried that before but as I'm also using PHP there was something wrong with the server, that I couldn't find. Thanks.

Comment: @DraganMarjanovic have a look at a properly aligned background.image: http://jsfiddle.net/wRtpR/ . Glad I could help;)

Answer (score 5):

if `<input type="image">` doesn't work as expected just try instead

```
<button type="submit"><img src="myimage.png"></button>
```

but as I wrote in the comment above your code should work fine too

Comment: Hmm I tried this but the image is misaligned and off... The image only looks correct when done as a
`<input type="image" src="myimage.png">`
but then it doesn't have submit functionality.

Comment: be sure to override all specific button style like margin, border and padding and, please, post a fiddle showing exactly what's wrong with style

Comment: I found out that the problem wasn't the HTML it was issues with the server. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Use a button element and style it with css. Don't omit the text, you form should be [accessible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_accessibility) without images or css.

```
<button type='submit'>Informative submit text</button>

button {
    background-image:url('myimage.png');
}
```

Comment: Ive tried this button my image always seems to be misaligned, and yes all my margins are set to 0.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone needs a newer html5 good answer:

```
<button id='' name=''  value='' ><img src='img.jpg' /></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="image" src="myimage.png">
```

or

```
<input type="submit" style="background:url(myimage.png)">
```