# get value from input using hyperlink

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make an edit form by echoing the input field. The problem is  my code did not detect the input value that I changed in the edit form. When I clicked the update hyperlink, I got "undefined index" at the POST variable. I'm wondering, what is the correct way to solve this problem?

[image: If I click the discette image it will do the editLanguage.php]

## edit.html

```
<?php
  // connect to the database
  include('Connections/connect.php');

  $studentId = ($_SESSION['student']);

  if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tbllanguage WHERE studentId=$studentId"))
  {
    if ($result->num_rows != 0) {

      // display data in table

      echo "<p>";              
      echo "<div id='body'>";
      echo "<div id='content'>";
      echo "<table align='center' border='0' width='400'>";
      echo "<tr> <th>Language</th> <th>Spoken</th>  <th>Writen</th> <th></th><th></th><th></th></tr>";

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        // echo out the contents of each row into a table
        echo "<form id=\"Form".$row[0]."\" accept-charset='UTF-8'>";//DO THIS: ADD THIS
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' id='".$row[0]."'>";//DO THIS: ADD THIS
        //echo "<input type='text' name='id' value='".$row[0]."'>";   

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo '<select id="language" name="language" style="width:200px;float:left;" class="form-control">
                <option value='.$row[1].'> '.$row[1].'</option>
                <option value="Malay">Malay</option>
                <option value="English">English</option>
                <option value="Chinese">Chinese</option>
                <option value="Tamil">Tamil</option>
              </select>';
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo '<select id="spoken" name="spoken" style="width:200px;float:left;" class="form-control">
                <option value='. $row[2] .'>'. $row[2] .'</option>
                <option value="Very Good">Very Good</option>
                <option value="Good">Good</option>
                <option value="Moderate">Moderate</option>
                <option value="Bad">Bad</option>
                <option value="Very Bad">Very Bad</option>
              </select>';
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo '<select name="writen" id="writen" style="width:200px;float:left;" class="form-control">
                <option value='. $row[3] .'>'. $row[3] .'</option>
                <option value="Very Good">Very Good</option>
                <option value="Good">Good</option>
                <option value="Moderate">Moderate</option>
                <option value="Bad">Bad</option>
                <option value="Very Bad">Very Bad</option>
              </select>';
        echo "</td>";
        echo '<td>'. "&nbsp;" .'</td>';
        echo "<td>";
        echo '<a href="deleteLanguage.php?id=' . $row[0] . '"><img src="image/delete.png" width="16" height="16" /></a>';
        echo "</td>";
        echo '<td>'. "&nbsp;" .'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. "&nbsp;" .'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. "&nbsp;" .'</td>';
        echo "<td>";
        echo '<a href="#" id="'.$row[0].'" onclick="editData(this.id)"><img src="image/save.png" width="16" height="16" /></a>';
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
      }

      echo "</table>";
      echo "</div>";
      echo "</div>";
      echo "</center>";
      echo "<p></p>";
      echo '<input type="submit" value="Cancel" id="btnCancel" name="cancel" class="btn btn-danger" />';
      echo "</form>";

    }
  }

  // close database connection
  $mysqli->close();

?>
```

## editLanguage.php

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  // connect to the database
  include('Connections/connect.php');

  function renderForm($id='')
    if (isset($_POST['id']) && is_numeric($_POST['id']))
    {  
      $id = $_POST['id'];
      $language = $_POST['language'];
      $spoken = $_POST['spoken'];
      $writen = $_POST['writen'];

      // update record from database
      if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE tbllanguage SET language = ?, spoken = ?, writen = ? WHERE languageId=?"))
      {
        $stmt->bind_param("sssi",$language,$spoken,$writen, $id);  
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        echo "Success";//return this string to js if form success
      } else {
         echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
      } 
    }

  $mysqli->close();

?>
```

## Javascript

```
<script>
function editData(id) {
    var url = "editLanguage.php";
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var formId = "Form"+id;
    if (confirm("Confirm update data?")) {
        var form = document.getElementById(formId);
        var formData = new FormData(form);
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
               if (xhttp.responseText == "Success"){
                   //alert("Updated successfully");
                   //location.reload(true);
                   window.document.write(xhttp.responseText);
               }else{
                   //alert("Something went wrong");
                   //location.reload(true);  
                     window.document.write(xhttp.responseText);                        
               }   
           }                       
       }

        xhttp.open("POST",url,true);
        xhttp.send(formData);
    }else{
        alert("Cancelled, no changes made.");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Firstly, did you instruct Apache to treat edit.html as PHP?

Comment: yes..i already have a .htaccess to treat html as php

Comment: you will need to be precise about *"i got undefined index at the POST variable"*, which variable? you have many.

Comment: in this line inside the editlanguage.php  $id = $_GET['id'];
      $language = $_POST['language'];
      $spoken = $_POST['spoken'];
      $writen = $_POST['writen'];

Comment: since im using echo in the html its not working like usual

Comment: ok but what's the exact error message? plus, did you start the session and for all pages using sessions? and how are you calling the `renderForm()` function?

Comment: undefined index: language ,undefined index: spoken, undefined index: writen..there is no problem with the session in my all other form

Comment: Your edit.html file does not have a closing `</form>` tag. If that is missing from your real code, add it and try again.

Comment: i have it actually..only because im trying to make the code shorter,so i just put the main code in here..im just wondering how to get the input value into the variable since only what not working..i tried to call the dropdownlist name in the variable but its not working

Comment: assuming the user click on this link  echo '<a href="editLanguage.php?id=' . $row[0] . '">, they will be brought to editlanguage.php, ok, so far so good, but even if you do this      $id = $_GET['id'];
      $language = $_POST['language'];
      $spoken = $_POST['spoken'];
      $writen = $_POST['writen'];m yes, the $_GET['id'] is true because it his pass through the url, but $_POST was never. that explain undefined index, language, spoken, written are all suppose to be in POST array

Comment: agreed ^ you need a submit button instead.

Comment: so how do i solve this? i try using GET but still same problem

Comment: so its not possible using hyperlink? is it possible if i put the edit function into the html?

Comment: pardon my horrible typing earlier. I do not know why you need an edit or what you are trying to achieve, can only see point out the possible error in your code. But as and as @Fred-ii- suggested, use a submit button as edit will be more consistent.

Comment: im just wondering since delete function got no problem with that..so i have no choice instead using button? i love to use hyperlink because i can put image in it

Comment: button can be styled with image as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329793/styling-buttons-with-images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit.html**

```
<?php
    //DO THIS: REMOVE THIS-> <form id='frmlanguage' action='editLanguage.php' method='post' accept- charset='UTF-8'>


    //.....your own code until.....

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

   // echo out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<form id=\"Form".$row[0]."\" accept-charset='UTF-8'>";//DO THIS: ADD THIS

    echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row[0]."'>"; 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo '<select id="language" name="language"  style="width:200px;float:left;" class="form-control">
            <option value='.$row[1].'> '.$row[1].'</option>
            <option value="Malay">Malay</option>
            <option value="English">English</option>
          </select>';

    //your own code until......
    echo '<a href="#" id="'.$row[0].'" onclick="editData(this.id)"><img src="image/save.png" width="16" height="16" /></a>';//DO THIS <- Assign onclick event

    //rest of your code until....
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Cancel" id="btnCancel" name="cancel" class="btn btn-danger" />';  
    echo "</form>";//DO THIS <- close form tag.
  }
}
  // close database connection
  $mysqli->close();
?>
```

**JavaScript**

```
//this can be placed anywhere in edit.html, preferably at the <head> section
//but place it outside <?php /*don't put here*/ ?> tag. or you can use a link to it, even better.
<script>
function editData(id) {
    var url = "editLanguage.php";
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var formId = "Form"+id;
    if (confirm("Confirm update data?")) {
    var form = document.getElementById(formId);
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                        if (xhttp.responseText == "Success"){
                            alert("Updated successfully");
                            location.reload(true);
                        }else{
                            alert("Something went wrong");
                            location.reload(true);                          
                        }   
                    }                       
                }

            xhttp.open("POST",url,true);
            xhttp.send(formData);
        }else{
            alert("Cancelled, no changes made.");
        return false;
        }
}
</script>
```

**editLanguage.php**

```
//remove unnecessary code, we don't require any other things else here except for validation or argument
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// connect to the database
include('Connections/connect.php');

if (isset($_POST['id'])// && is_numeric($_POST['id']))
   {  
      $id = $_POST['id'];
      $language = $_POST['language'];
      $spoken = $_POST['spoken'];
      $writen = $_POST['writen'];

      // update record from database
      if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE tbllanguage SET language = ?, spoken = ?, writen = ? WHERE languageId=?"))
      {
         //$stmt->bind_param("sssi",$language,$spoken,$writen, $id);  
         $stmt->execute(array($language,$spoken,$written,$id));
         $stmt->close();
         echo "Success";//return this string to js if form success
      } else {
         echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
      } 
  }
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

What is going on here?

**1. We assign a form id to every row of result we return.**

```
//echo "<form id=\"Form".$row[0]."\" accept-charset='UTF-8'>"; Form+id
//return Form1, Form2, Form3 and so on, id generated using the result
//from the query. It will look like:
    <form id="Form1" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

**2. We assign an onclick event to trigger a js function.**

The function we are triggering is editData as below, and passing along this hyperlink id along, href="#" will return nothing, for this example purpose, we just do not want this link upon click, redirect the page to anywhere else.

```
echo '<a href="#" id="'.$row[0].'" onclick="editData(this.id)"><img src="image/save.png" width="16" height="16" /></a>';
```

It will look like:

```
<a href="#" id="1" onclick="editData(this.id)"><img src="image/save.png" width="16" height="16"></a>
```

When the Javascript function gets triggered, we get the id of the hyperlink pass along, since we have set, the numeric id of the hyperlink is the same of the form we created, hence we have create a reference to the form.

```
    var url = "editlanguage.php";//send the form to this page

    var formId = "Form"+id;// return string Form1, Form2 or so on.

    if (confirm("Confirm update data?"))....//just a confirmation box

    var form = document.getElementById(formId);//get Form byFormId set earlier as var formId

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {......//the magical moment, read more about it.


if (xhttp.responseText == "Success"){//if string success is returned by editLanguage
                            alert("Updated successfully");
                            location.reload(true);//refresh page
                        }else{
                            alert("Something went wrong");
                            location.reload(true);  //refresh page                      

alert("Cancelled, no changes made.");....//if cancel is click.
```

**3. The query in editLanguage.php will query the result, all using POST var, and we only want to return a string "Success" because we are "listening" to this string from the Javascript to prompt an alert as mentioned above.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: ur code can send the value but only the first value only..but im working in multiple data from database..tq for ur help btw..i will try to do something to make it work

Comment: don;t get what you meant or trying to achieve, all post parameters within the form can be send. goodluck mate.

Comment: maybe u will get some idea if u look at the image i just added..if i click the discette image it will do the editLanguage.function

Comment: aha! Now we understand what you mean, ok, so you want to delete it without redirecting it or?

Comment: no..update without redirect..the delete fuction already worked

Comment: now this gets a little tricky, as you can simply delete by using the rowid, but as for update on a particular row without redirect and without submitting the whole form, are you comfortable using a little js? or you still prefer using pure php? but requires a refresh, but I think that will update whatever changes on the page instead of the row, so its a downside.

Comment: i dont really understand js since im very new to php..i think better for me if i can make it work using php only like my delete function..maybe u can give me a hint or link so that i can try it

Comment: ok, i write u something when when i get home tonight. its morning at my side now... ;)

Comment: Here you go, hope it helps.

Comment: ty for ur help..i have tried your code and it seems i got a popup alert saying that "something went wrong"..what does it mean? does it mean i have gone wrong in my update query?

Comment: Hi, can u update your question with your new editLanguage.php code?

Comment: okay..i have updated my latest editLaguage.php based on ur code..i have tried to echo the $id,$language but still got same alert

Comment: I see, we are very near there now, as your script runs fine, otherwise you won't even have any pop up. Ok, now lets try some debugging. remove the rederform function, remove the sssi, and remove the script inside editlanguage.php

Comment: still same alert.. how do i check whether the id is passed to the editLanguage.php or not?

Comment: i create a new temporary answer for this debugging sake. lets change instead alert, we open a new window and start to debug